# ms excel how to find max time for each athlete?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
usa,      Texas     : 15
usa,      NY        : 20

uk ,      London     : 9.9
uk ,      Manchester : 10.8
```

Imagine the above as being in lists column A -country, B -city, C-temp
I have looked at the max if nested array formula in excel but it would only return 20 the max value. I want to see for each unique combination of country and city which has the highest temperature. So would want a formula to return  usa, NY : 20 and uk , Manchester : 10.8 . Please advise?

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason, every keeps asking about [Excel's Subtotals feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-subtotals-in-a-list-of-data-in-a-worksheet-7881d256-b4fa-4f81-b71e-b0a3d4a52b3a), as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

For your information, I've switched the "Temp" and "Town" columns, because in order to get more information (like the town name) of a subtotal, you might try to use the `VLookup()` function and in order to use that function, the value you're looking up must be located in the first column.

Comment: Brilliant! I did not know it was possible to use the Max function on subtotals! Many thanks. Index Match could be used in this case then as it does not have the first column limitation.

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer helps you, please upvote or accept it (this is how this site works).